# Erlang sudoku solver - How to find the empty spots and try possible values recursively

Tags: recursion, erlang, sudoku

I have been busy with a sudoku solver in Erlang yesterday and today. The working functionality I have now is that I can check if a sudoku in the form of a list, e.g.,

```
[6,7,1,8,2,3,4,9,5,5,4,9,1,7,6,3,2,8,3,2,8,5,4,9,1,6,7,1,3,2,6,5,7,8,4,9,9,8,6,4,1,2,5,7,3,4,5,7,3,9,8,6,1,2,8,9,3,2,6,4,7,5,1,7,1,4,9,3,5,2,8,6,2,6,5,7,8,1,9,3,4].
```

is valid or not by looking at the constraints (no duplicates in squares, rows, and columns).

This function is called valid(S) which takes a sudoku S and returns true if it is a valid sudoku and false if it is not. The function ignores 0's, which are used to represent empty values. This is an example of the same sudoku with some random empty values:

```
[0,7,1,8,2,3,4,0,5,5,4,9,0,7,6,3,2,8,3,0,8,5,0,9,1,6,7,1,3,2,6,5,7,8,4,9,0,8,6,4,1,2,5,7,0,4,5,7,3,9,8,6,1,0,8,9,3,2,6,4,7,5,1,7,1,4,9,3,0,2,8,6,2,6,5,7,8,1,9,3,4].
```

The next step is to find the first 0 in the list, and try a value from 1 to 9 and check if it produces a valid sudoku. If it does we can continue to the next 0 and try values there and see if it is valid or not. Once we cannot go further we go back to the previous 0 and try the next values et cetera until we end up with a solved sudoku.

The code I have so far looks like this (based on someone who got it almost working):

```
solve(First,Nom,[_|Last]) -> try_values({First,Nom,Last},pos()).

try_values(_,[]) -> {error, "No solution found"};
try_values({First,Nom,Last},[N|Pos]) ->
  case valid(First++[N]++Last) of
    true ->
      case solve({First++[N]},Nom,Last) of
        {ok,_} -> {ok, "Result"};
        {error,_} -> try_values({First,N,Last},Pos)
      end;
    false -> try_values({First,N,Last},Pos)
  end.
```

pos() is a list consisting of the values from 1 to 9. The idea is that we enter an empty list for First and a Sudoku list for [_|Last] in which we look for a 0 (Nom?). Then we try a value and if the list that results is valid according to our function we continue till we fail the position or have a result. When we fail we return a new try_values with remaining (Pos) values of our possibitilies.

Naturally, this does not work and returns:

```
5> sudoku:solve([],0,S).
** exception error: bad argument
     in operator  ++/2
        called as {[6]}
                  ++
                  [1,1,8,2,3,4,0,5,5,4,9,0,7,6,3,2,8,3,2,8,5,4,9,1,6,7,1,3,2|...]
     in call from sudoku:try_values/2 (sudoku.erl, line 140)
     in call from sudoku:try_values/2 (sudoku.erl, line 142)
```

With my inexperience I cannot grasp what I need to do to make the code logical and working. I would really appreciate it if someone with more experience could give me some pointers.

Comment: The error comes from `solve({First++[N]},Nom,Last)`, as far as I can tell `solve` expects `First` to be a list, then you probably meant `solve(First++[N],Nom,Last)`

Comment: Hi you again, thanks! :-) This was indeed not right. Unfortunately I still have the issue now. The main problem I have is that I do not understand how to iterate recursively over the 0's. I think that the Nom variable has to work with this but I do not know how. Full code is here https://github.com/erooijak/Erlang/blob/master/sudoku.erl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try_values([], []) -> error("No solution found");
try_values([Solution], []) -> Solution;
try_values(_, []) -> error("Bad sudoku: multiple solutions");
try_values(Heads, [0|Tail]) ->
    NewHeads = case Heads of
                   [] -> [[P] || P <- pos()];
                   _ -> [Head++[P] || P <- pos(), Head <- Heads]
              end,
    ValidHeads = [Head || Head <- NewHeads, valid(Head++Tail)],
    try_values(ValidHeads, Tail);
try_values([], [H|Tail]) -> try_values([[H]], Tail);
try_values(Heads, [H|Tail]) -> try_values([Head++[H] || Head <- Heads], Tail).

solve(Board) ->
    case valid(Board) of
        true -> try_values([], Board);
        false -> error("No solution found")
    end.
```

`try_values` does what you described. It builds solution by going through `Board`, trying all possible solutions (from `pos()`) when it finds `0` and collecting `valid` solutions in `ValidHeads` to pass them further to continue. Thus, it goes all possible ways, if at some point there are multiple `valid` sudoku they all will be added to `Heads` and will be tested on `valid`ity on following steps. `solve` is just a wrapper to call `try_values([], Board)`.

Basically, the way to `iterate recursively over 0's` is to skip all non-zeros (2 last `try_values` expression) and do the job on zeros (fourth `try_values` expression).

First three `try_values` expressions check if solution is exist and single and return it in that case.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have trouble understanding the dropwhile part. The head ( fun (H) ? ) gets dropped from the list when head + tailH++tail are not valid. And then you use an end and put a NewHeads behind the comma? The Erlang manual for [dropwhile/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#dropwhile-2) does not explain what this does. I also don't understand how the case of [] and [Validhead|_] can follow from this. Last but not least, for somewhat more difficult sudoku's it says "solution not found" (while there is a solution). I don't understand how this can be since it is just brute forcing.

Comment: @user2609980 sorry, my bad. I did it wrong. I assumed that at any given point there is only one `valid` solution and skipped all others. Thus, previous code went only one way in a tree of all possible boards. I updated my answer. `dropwhile/2` skips elements of list until given predicate is `true` and then returns the rest of a list. This way when `dropwhile` matched `[]` there were no valid solutions, and when it matched [ValidHead|_], valid was one possible solution. Anyway it was wrong.

Comment: Aha! Now I understand what went wrong with the previous code. And the "end" bit I did not understand is now clear after you put an enter in the code. Naturally, if a sudoku has multiple solutions it is not bad, but it should display the two solutions. I leave that as an exercise to myself ;-). Thanks a lot good sir!

Comment: It works on most sudoku's, but when I try the world's most difficult Sudoku it thinks for 10 minutes and then you get the following error: "Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
eheap_alloc: Cannot allocate 1366780092 bytes of memory (of type "heap")". How can this be? :-)

Comment: @user2609980 It means the algorithm (bruteforce) is not good enough and requires too much memory for those cases. You need to find better Sudoku solving algorithm.